# Is it possible to direct certain client traffic to the same pod? Not sticky sessions but clients that need to connect to the same pod

Tags: kubernetes

I have a situation where a group of clients need to connect to the same pod.  The pods are stateful and contains session specific info.   Clients need to be given some kind of id the will direct them to the correct pod.   Not exactly sticky sessions though.    The session is created on a pod by one client, and then other clients given the location id to join that pods session.  If I run the app as a single instance, everything work great, because all sessions are on the same pod.  But, as soon as the pod is scaled out, sessions can be created anywhere, and participant clients are not able to find the session, and thus don't receive the data.

I'm trying to work around a problem where this app is not only stateful, but also not distributable.   Ideally, session data would be in a message queue, and any pod should be able to receive the session info.  But, these are the cards I've been dealt.

TIA for any help or advice you can give.

ADDENDUM:  The devs will be refactoring the app to utilize some kind of MQ.  So, I'm not looking for suggestions to share session info.   I'm looking for a fix that will route traffic specific clients to a specific pod.   I personally don't believe this will be possible, just trying on the off chance it is.  Right now the only option is to run the app as on giant pod that will handle all client session.

Comment: *fix that will route traffic specific clients to a specific pod* - how do you recognize those specific clients? are you using some cookies or sth to differentiate between them?

Comment: there is an api call that is somthing like this ...
     app.com/join/0039
...with 0039 being the ID of the session.

Comment: I don't think there is a quick fix to it. You could probably try to write proxy app to handle forwarding requests to appropriate pods and it may somehow work but the best way is to just rewrite the main app to be stateless as you already mentioned.